# Общий custon Top Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Хочу создать один класс для верхнего бара, в плане графики все подвязывается, а вот селекторы на методы из этого класса для кнопок не работают, подскажите как это можно реализовать ??

```
//Отдельный класс создания бара

@implementation TopBarDrow

//Метод создания верхнего бара со всеми кнопками нанесенными на него

- (void)drowTopBarView:(UIView*)mainView labelText:(UILabel*)label;

{

    //Основное view верхнего topBar---------------

    UIView* topBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
    topBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [mainView addSubview:topBarView];

    //Кнопка меню---------------------------------

    UIButton * buttonMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [buttonMenu setTitle:@"H" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonMenu.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    buttonMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
    [topBarView addSubview:buttonMenu];

}


//Метод действия кнопки------------

- (void)actionButtonMenu

{

    NSLog(@"Hello");

}

//Реализация класса во ViewController

    TopBarDrow * topBarDrowViewController = [TopBarDrow new];
    [topBarDrowViewController drowTopBarView:self.view labelText:nil];
```

При такой реализации кнопка buttonMenu на работает, прошу указать на мою ошибку...

Comment: Для кнопки необходимо добавить селектор - `[buttonMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(actionButtonMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: Спс, поправил но ситуация не изменилась...

Comment: `initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)` - проблема может быть тут, так как айфон 6 имеет более широкий экран. Можете попробовать понажимать на топБар в других местах, кнопка может сработать. Замените `320` на `mainView.frame.size.width`. Надеюсь это Вам поможет.

Comment: я создавал топ бар с точно такими-же параметрами во viewController, кнопку то я вижу, она не нажимается... И там же создавал метод, все работало, вопрос в переносе метода...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем решении контроллером является self.view, если вы перенесете метод `- (void)actionButtonMenu` в контроллер, он будет работать без других изменений. Если же хотите оставить метод в классе `TopBarDrow`, сделайте так:

Замените `[mainView addSubview:topBarView];` на `[self addSubview:topBarView];` и в контроллере замените на

```
TopBarDrow * topBarDrowViewController = [[TopBarDrow alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
[topBarDrowViewController drowTopBarView:self.view labelText:nil];
[self.view addSubview:topBarDrowViewController];
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо !